# "Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.,uncaughtException: Connection lost: The server closed the connection"

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am getting the error after 8-12 hours of starting my node.  I have set a `cron` for every hour to query my SQL database and keep my connection alive though this is happening.

```
"stack": ["Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.", "    at Protocol.end (/path/to/my/file/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:109:13)", "    at Socket.<anonymous> (/path/to/my/file/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:102:28)", "    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)", "    at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)", "    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)", "    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)", "    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:397:17)"],
"level": "error",
"message": "uncaughtException: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.",
"timestamp": "2017-09-13T21:22:25.271Z"
```

Let me explain my code.  I have a common mySQL connection code to pass with my all API's.  My common database connection code is as below.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var db_connect = (function () {
    function db_connect() {
        mysqlConnConfig = {
            host: "localhost",
            user: "username",
            password: "password",
            database: "db_name"
        };
    }
    db_connect.prototype.unitOfWork = function (sql) {
    mysqlConn = mysql.createConnection(mysqlConnConfig);
        try {
            sql(mysqlConn);
        } catch (ex) {

            console.error(ex);
        } finally {
            mysqlConn.end();
        }
    };
    return db_connect;
})();
exports.db_connect = db_connect;
```

So I am getting this function in all my API's:

```
db_connect.prototype.unitOfWork = function (sql)
```

I will query my database in all my API's with the above function as below.

```
var query1 = "SELECT * FROM table1";
 sql.query(query1,function(error,response){
if(error){
    console.log(error);
}
else{
    console.log(response);
    }
 })
```

I had tried several times for more than 2 weeks to solve this issue as this is killing my node and I need to restart it everytime whenever it goes down.
Can anybody get me with the solution? 
Put simply, what I need is how to use the below code and put it with my code structure(my common db connection file)?

```
var db_config = {
  host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'example'
};

var connection;

function handleDisconnect() {
  connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config); // Recreate the connection, since
                                                  // the old one cannot be reused.

  connection.connect(function(err) {              // The server is either down
    if(err) {                                     // or restarting (takes a while sometimes).
      console.log('error when connecting to db:', err);
      setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 2000); // We introduce a delay before attempting to reconnect,
    }                                     // to avoid a hot loop, and to allow our node script to
  });                                     // process asynchronous requests in the meantime.
                                          // If you're also serving http, display a 503 error.
  connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('db error', err);
    if(err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') { // Connection to the MySQL server is usually
      handleDisconnect();                         // lost due to either server restart, or a
    } else {                                      // connnection idle timeout (the wait_timeout
      throw err;                                  // server variable configures this)
    }
  });
}

handleDisconnect();
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried connection pooling using `DBIx`? http://search.cpan.org/~adrianwit/DBIx-Connection-0.13/lib/DBIx/Connection.pm

Comment: no i havent tried that.

Comment: I agree with @alvits. You should certainly use a connection pool and you should certainly not try to use a long-running connection.

Comment: Can you help me
With the code?

Comment: But I am closing the connection after every request?